# Remote Control for Pulse Audio?

Tags: android, remote-access, pulseaudio

I'm eager fro remote control on a pulse audio system and having awesome trouble finding a solution. On-line searches are confounded by endless hits on remote streaming (sending sound from pulse audio to a remote device), and it is hard to find even a mention of remote control.

I have found reverb:

https://github.com/hchapman/reverb

which is the hottest candidate by a mile, but the app isn't available anywhere I can find for installing on an android phone, much rather it looks a) seriously unmaintained, last touched 7 years ago and b) looks non-trivial to build because of long dead and dated dependencies. Forsooth. Anyone got a modern build?

Then I also found PaWebControl:

https://github.com/Siot/PaWebControl

and while that is more alive (has far more recent code activity) is sub-optimal (would mean using a web browser on a phone to control pulseaudio, or checking if it has or giving it a REST API and writing an app that talks to it - but then that seems overkill and like more work than getting reverb working again!).

I am I admit deeply bamboozled at why this is not a standad thing, with a solid solution. Why? Because on my sound system (which is on a surround sound HTPC with Kodi installed), there are literally (at least) three chained volume controls:

1. Kodi
2. PulseAudio
3. My AV Receiver (that drives the speakers)

Of those three:

1. Kodi has a remote (Kore)
2. Is a problem
3. Has a remote (a phone app)

So who cares? Clearly very few people which is what puzzles me, but here is the catch, the Linux volume control (available in the system tray) adjusts Pulse Audio volume. Crucial to know and to understand. It can control app volume too but that's still a Pulse Audio control. And this is problematic if you share your system eitehr with other people or otehr apps (and I do both).

So if other people are around, they fiddle the volume using the system control, so pulse audio sometimes, and it gets set low and I'm downstairs in my workshop and can't crank the volume up high enough to enjoy properly, Kore at max, AV receiver at max ... and it's because someone set the Linux volume down earlier in the day and I have to physically to the PC to up it again.

If other apps are on the same PC indeed, they may be running at same time, sound elsewhere, or just at other times, but either way there are plenty of times, it's useful to manipulate the apps volume and other times the systems (bringing all apps up or down in volume).

And so I would feel so much more comfortable and in control if anywhere around the house on wifi I could control Kodi's volume, the AV receiver's columns (check and check) AND pulse audio's volume. Only this middle on causes grief.

And I admit that share the reasons not because they are in the least relevant, it is a totally understandable desire to remote control pulseaudio for a hundred other reasons, but (and here is decades of on-line experience talking) I want to forestall the inevitable (and I admit unwelcome) questioning of why I want to remote control pulse audio. I just do.

What I'm interested in is a solution (remote control of Pulse Audio), not a workaround (I have those).

Now I see a clue in PaWebControl as it has pactl as a dependency, so I installed that, and sure enough pactl has a --server option and that could conceivably connect to a pulse audio server on another system and control it!

But can I find any examples, no? Again all searches I've done are confounded by endless networking tips to get pulseaudio streaming music on a network. But I find no useful tips or clues on how to pactl to control a remote pulseaudio system, nor can I find any apps to do that that are easily available.

My guess is, the easiest solution is to build reverb again but that doesn't look easy and so has been on my todo list for a long long time and still is. It was finding mention of PaWebControl today that prompted me to reopen this todo and see where it was at. And where it's at, is hoping someone on SO knows something I don't and can remote control pulseaudio (ideally from a phone, which is pretty much how every remote works now).

Comment: For the first repo check: https://github.com/hchapman/reverb/issues/6

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't spot that. It works, albeit it's flaky and crashes a lot. I would love to see if there are other tools I've missed (not found) or someone can get Reverb built and maintained again!